# Public Access to OWA Calendar

Tags: permissions, exchange, exchange-2007, outlook-web-app, calendar

I'm looking for some assistance with the permissions needed to allow anonymous/public access to a mailbox in Exchange 2007 (soon to be Exchange 2010).  The access needs to be able to view the calendar appointments, but not appointment specifics and must not require a login to see the contents.

I'm aware how to point people to the resouce, but haven't yet found the trick to the permissions.  URL for access would be http://exchange.school.edu/owa/[mailbox_SMTP_address]/?cmd=contents&module=calendar.

Anyone accomplished this or have a recommendation?

Answer (score 3):

Exchange 2010 SP1 introduces Internet Calendar Sharing, which essentially allows you to do what you want. The Exchange team posted a [very detailed blog post](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2011/02/16/458128.aspx) recently about the topic, which I highly recommend you read over.

Basically, Exchange publishes your calendar in iCal format which anybody can subscribe to. The instructions to set it up are in [this TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607475.aspx) article.

Comment: This is the way to do it. Don't try to hack something together outside of this kind of framework or you're likely to either break OWA or open a massive security hole.

Comment: Sounfds great, but I'm really looking for a solution now rather than this fall when we migrate to 2010.  I have a faculty (and they run the place) who is having new issues with syncing their calendar with 3rd party tools and would rather make our existing tools (OWA/Exchange) work rather than make something like Tungle or Google Calendar Sync work.

Comment: @edusysadmin - sorry I don't know anything that does what you want pre Exchange 2010 SP1. I guess you could roll something with EWS, but that would require programming knowledge and the time to create such an application.